# xmessage in a script freezes

Tags: shell-script, x11

I use the following script called from a udev rule in order to automate backup:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0
export XAUTHORITY=/home/gauthier/.Xauthority

# ... other things like offering abort, checking the device, mounting.

export OUTPUT=/tmp/rsync-output.log

# -a does not work on exFAT partitions, because of permissions, groups, owner. Use -rltD instead of -rlptgoD, which -a would imply.
sudo rsync -rltDv --exclude '*.app' --exclude-from=/home/gauthier/rsync-exclude.txt /home/gauthier/ $MOUNTPOINT/gauthier/ > $OUTPUT 2>&1

# Pop up a result window
# Get a summary
export RESULT_MESSAGE=/tmp/rsync-result.txt
echo "Backup result:" > $RESULT_MESSAGE
echo "" >> $RESULT_MESSAGE    # \n does not seem to work in echo strings
tail -3 $OUTPUT >> $RESULT_MESSAGE
echo "" >> $RESULT_MESSAGE
echo "" >> $RESULT_MESSAGE
echo "Details in $OUTPUT" >> $RESULT_MESSAGE
xmessage -file $RESULT_MESSAGE
```

The popping of the result window (the last row) does not work. Not only the window does not appear, the following commands after this are not executed.

What could make xmessage freeze, and how can I solve it?
I am sure there are better ways to format a message, I'd be happy with insight about that as well.

---

Could `echo` and `>>` still be working on the file while I try to run xmessage on it? The 8 rows work alright when I paste them (with the newlines) in a terminal, but I guess the timing could be different since the prompt appears. Plus I am not superuser when I run it by hand. Aren't `echo` and `>>` supposed to be completed before going to the next command?

Answer (score 0):

`xmessage` is obsolete and no longer maintained: it does not support UTF-8, etc. You should you `gxmessage` instead (xmessage clone based on GTK+).

Comment: Is it? That would explain that it's not working well, but I still wouldn't expect it to break in such a basic case. I'm not very likely to run a desktop that hasn't gtk so I'll test with gxmessage. However, gxmessage is not installed by default in Ubuntu, while xmessage is. I'd rather skip the dependency and not require installing non-default programs. So I'm still interested in making xmessage work.

Comment: @Gauthier Perhaps it works but the window is displayed off-screen because of some obscure setting of your window manager (that would explain why the following commands are not executed). You can also check the behavior with `gxmessage` or some other X program such as `xterm` in place of `xmessage`.

Comment: I can test with `-center` to xmessage, but if it does appear off-screen, the following commands *should* be run, shouldn't they?

Comment: @Gauthier No, with both `xmessage` and `gxmessage`, the corresponding process still runs until you click on the OK button. So, the following commands won't be executed until then (or you need to run `xmessage` or `gxmessage` in background by using `&`).

Comment: Of course, you're right, silly mistake! I'll give `-center` a shot, but all the other xmessage windows in the script appear ok on the screen. No icon in Unity's task bar either.

Comment: I am considering testing a short `sleep` before running `xmessage`, see my update.